# Detecting new links and adding them to db

Tags: php, mysqli

I `fetch` a page for finding and collecting some of its links (using `arrays`), and add them to database. when "refetching" source page, it maybe have new links. how i can avoid inserting old links to db and only add new links?

one idea can be searching every fetched link in db and avoid inserting double ones, but it use heavy source in big database.

Comment: If you make a unique index on the URL, trying to insert a duplicate will not be allowed. You can use `ON DUPLICATE KEY IGNORE` to make it fail silently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make the field 'url' uniq in the table with :

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE mytbl ADD UNIQUE (columnName);
```

And then go through every link and add them, if the field exist mysql with reject it.

If you have a granted access to the page you are scrapping, you could add an class which say when you already get through this url. and then only lookup the link without
 this class.

Answer (score 0):

You can add in database, with your links info, an hash computed in algorithms like MD5 (16 bytes) or SHA-1 (30 bytes) to check if hash exists.